# Using Multiple Languages while developing a Spark application

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a project with another person. My part of the project involves analytics with Spark's Machine Learning, while my teammate is using Spark Streaming to pipeline data from the source to the program and out to an interface.

I am planning to use Scala since it has the best support for Spark. However, my teammate does not have any experience with Scala, and would probably prefer to use Python.

Given that our parts of the program are doing two different things, would it be a good idea for us to have his Python script call my Scala executable? Or would using different languages raise complications later on?

Comment: PySpark and Spark are two projects running side by side. If you're starting fresh, go with Scala, the updates to the API are more frequent and you always get new features first. Learning Scala is the same as learning any other language, you'll benefit from it down the road.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question is being primarily opinion based.

Comment: I do not think this question is primarily opinion-based. I am asking a well-defined question - "Would using different languages raise complications later on?" - that could be answered by examples of why or why not using a two-language approach may or may not be appropriate for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

An experienced developer will be able to pick up a new language and become productive fairly quickly.

I would only consider using the two languages together if:

1. The deadlines are too tight to allow for the developer to get up to speed,
2. The integration between the modules is quite limited (and you're confident that won't change) and
3. There is a clear deployment strategy.

I would suggest doing a small-scale test first to confirm the deployment and integration plans you have will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am Python fanboy. 
When I start using Spark I little bit confuse in continuing use Python or switch to Scala or Java.

But after trying Python to develop some basic application, I was starting bored because the Python we use is not Python ordinary anymore and hard to debug may cause invisible issue.

So I switch to use Scala. Here why:

1. It's easy than you think.
2. You can learn from Spark Code Base and Know how Spark works.
3. It's awesome and much better than Java with lambda function.
4. Watch this [videos](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjs5aWooanNAhUMPY8KHYO3DW8QtwIIHDAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DLH75sJAR0hc&usg=AFQjCNFQ2DLuIyg17oXNTfX_0fqWbykPzQ&sig2=H8jGcwWGLS7AxDTsKW1K2A&bvm=bv.124272578,d.c2I)

Comment: lambda function is available since java 8